# How do I compare two integer value hashes?

Tags: ruby

I created a function that compares two hashes and returns a report on whether the subtraction of their values is negative or not.

The problem comes down to having a cost hash for a building and a current resources hash like:

```
cost = {:wood => 300, :stone => 200, :gold => 100}
reqs = {:wood => 200, :stone => 220, :gold => 90}
```

This one should return a report hash like:

```
report = { :has_resources => false, :has_wood =>  true, :has_stone => false, :has_gold => true }
```

Now, in the cost hash, `:gold`, `:stone` or `:wood` can be nil, i.e. non-existent.

My first attempt is definitely not the Ruby way and I don't like the function. It works, but I want to find a way to write it in a better manner:

```
def has_resources?(cost)
  report = { :has_resources => true, :has_wood =>  true, :has_stone => true, :has_gold => true } 
  if not cost[:wood].nil? 
    if self.wood < cost[:wood]
      report[:has_wood] = false
      report[:has_resources] = false 
    end
  end
  if not cost[:stone].nil? 
    if self.stone < cost[:stone]
      report[:has_stone] = false
      report[:has_resources] = false
    end
  end   
  if not cost[:gold].nil?
    if self.gold < cost[:gold]
      report[:has_gold] = false
      report[:has_resources] = false
    end
  end

end
```

How should I rewrite this? I don't like the `.nil?` checks here, but I have to include them since the `<` operator does not work on nil objects. I also don't like having so many `if`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a version that is a bit more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). It also makes use of ruby's default value for hashes, and I threw in a dummy class in order to make the tests actually run.

This could probably be done even better, but one thing you really should try to achieve when writing ruby code (or any code at all, for that matter) is to try not to repeat yourself too much. That's where DRY come in.

```
class CostCalculation
  attr_accessor :wood, :stone, :gold

  def initialize(reqs)
    self.wood = reqs[:wood] || 0
    self.stone = reqs[:stone] || 0
    self.gold = reqs[:gold] || 0
  end 

  def has_resources?(cost)
    report = Hash.new(true)
    cost.default = 0 

    attributes.each do |key, value|
      report[:"has_#{key}"] = cost[key] <= value
    end 

    if report.values.include?(false)
      report[:has_resources] = false
    end 

    report
  end 

  def attributes
    { wood: self.wood, stone: self.stone, gold: self.gold }   
  end 
end
```

...and here are some specs for it as well:

```
describe CostCalculation do
  it "has enough resources for something that's free" do
    report = CostCalculation.new({}).has_resources?({})
    report[:has_resources].should == true
  end 

  %w[wood stone gold].each do |resource|    
    it "does not have enough resources if #{resource} is missing" do
      cost = {resource.to_sym => 1}
      report = CostCalculation.new({wood: 0, stone: 0, gold: 0}).has_resources?(cost)

      report[:has_resources].should == false
      report[:"has_#{resource}"].should == false
    end 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Although, one thing that I'd really like to do with this, is that since the method name ends with a question mark, I'd want it to return a boolean, so that it returns false in the cases where the current version returns something with `report[:has_resources] == false`.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this is `report = Hash.new(true)`, I'd prefer `report[:pancakes]` to be `nil` (which would hopefully cause something to explode and fall over) rather than `true`. Altering `cost` might be an issue as well.

Comment: yeah, the question mark is a remainder actually, from my previous version, which return true or false. The new one should return a hash :)

Comment: Hm... Now that you mention it, @muistooshort, I actually agree with you. The part of modifying `cost` can be fixed by just cloning `cost` and modifying the clone. You could also do something similar with `report`, or just do `report.default = nil` before returning it, and also make sure to always set a value for `report[:has_resources]`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my version: Tested Working under ruby 1.8.7-p334

Assume inputs are:

```
cost = {:wood => 300, :stone => 200, :gold => 100}
reqs = {:wood => 200, :stone => 220, :gold => 90}
```

and in the cost hash,:gold, :stone or :wood can be nil.

```
def has_resources?(cost,reqs)
    result = cost.merge(reqs) { |key, cst, rqs| cst.nil?||(cst - rqs) > 0 ? true : false }
    result[:has_resources] = !result.has_value?(false)
    return result
end
```

It will return the result of:

```
{ :has_resources => false, :wood =>  true, :stone => false, :gold => true }
```

If you really want the result to have "has_wood","has_stone","has_gold" as key, you may need to modify the code to rename the key in result Hash. But I think it's not needed.

In case people ask why merge method? here is the [Ruby Hash Merge documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge)
When compare two hash with same key, I think "merge" method is the simple way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're repeating yourself through copy'n'paste code 
so that should be converted to some sort of iteration. Then bust 
it up into little pieces that can be nicely named and you'll have
something compact and readable:

```
MATERIALS = [ :wood, :stone, :gold ]

def resource_availability(costs)
    MATERIALS.reject(&have_enough_for(costs)).
              each_with_object(base_report, &not_enough) 
end

private

def have_enough_for(costs)
    ->(material) { costs[material].nil? || costs[material] < self.send(material) }
end

def has_sym(material)
    ('has_' + material.to_s).to_sym
end

def base_report
    MATERIALS.each_with_object({ :has_resources => true }) { |m, h| h[has_sym(m)] = true }
end

def not_enough
    ->(material, report) do
        report[has_sym(material)] = false
        report[:has_resources   ] = false
    end
end
```